# What is the best RAM upgrade for my Inspiron N5010

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, upgrade, dell-inspiron

My system model and specs: Dell Inspiron N5010 i5, 4GB(2x2) RAM and Mobile Intel 5 series express chipset HM57.

I am thinking to upgrade RAM to 8GB: 4gb x 4gb.I Would like to know the best suitable (High performance) RAM for my Laptop. I have searched most of the places like Corsair and Kingston's Websites and was not able to find the compatible RAM. Kindly let me know if HyperX RAMs are compatible with my system. Provide the Model # or links would be helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Neeth

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you have two options to check what would work either:

Go to Crucial Memory Scanner which is a tool you can download which will scan your machine and advise you on the best memory to get..

or

Go to Dell support page enter your service tag and it will bring up your manual which will have a list of compatibles memory modules.

Just to help you further your laptop takes SODIMM DDR3 1066MHz memory as per its Spec on the Dell page so most 4Gb modules of that spec will be compatible although I will not recommend a specific one as there is always a chance it is not compatible therefore would not want to get it wrong for you...

Comment: Thank you very much, Charles. System scanner shown me two Ram options. Is there any other RAM brands which provide system scanner? same like Crucial? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nithin No other ones as far as I'm aware however Crucial is very good memory so I would recommend it.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me out. I will go ahead and buy Crucial.